# How to recreate this image using css

Tags: css, html

I want to recreate this image for exercise purposes.

[image]

For that I'm nesting `div`s, and add a padding to them, like so (excerpt):

```
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-right: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
}

...

<body>
  <div>
    Content
    <div></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

But this doesn't quite seem to work. Is this actually the way to go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best I could come up with is:

#### html:

```
<div id="margin">
    <p>Margin</p>
    <div id="border">
        <p>Border</p>
        <div id="padding">
            <p>Padding</p>
            <div id="content">
                <p>Content</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
div {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 1em 1em 1em;
}

#margin {
    border: 1px dashed #ccc;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}

#border {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: #9f2;
}

#padding {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: #fff;
}

#content {
    border: 1px dashed #ccc;
    height: 2em;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/KWTTN/).

> For that I'm nesting `div`s, and add a padding to them...But this doesn't quite seem to work. Is this actually the way to go?

I think that this is the *only* way to go, given that the image sort of describes a hierarchical relationship between the various components, and the only alternative I could think of would be to use lots of `position: absolute` `div`s, which wouldn't convey, or imply, any kind of relationship between the various parts.

Comment: Is using <p> for the text better than just embedding text within the <div>? Sry to ask but I'm a bloody css noob ^^.

Comment: Honestly? I don't think it's a big deal either way =) The only reason I used a `p` is that it gives a CSS 'hook' to the text (allowing for further stylistic choices to be applied at a later date. It possibly *also* adds a semantic meaning/context to the contained text, but I'm not certain that it's a necessity.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/r5Vu9/ ?